# jQuery Carousel Stop at End

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a jQuery carousel that is populated using JSON. I need it to stop at the end. I calculate the width of the list by multiplying the number of list items by the width of the list item, so new items can be added without changing the width in the CSS. Here is my code

slider.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var w = $("#carouselList").css("width");

var slider = $("#carouselList");
var leftProperty, newLeftProperty;


$("#rightButton").click(function(){
    leftProperty = parseInt(slider.css("left"));

    if (leftProperty - 991 <= -w) {
        newLeftProperty = 0;

        }
    else {
        newLeftProperty = leftProperty - 304;

         }



    slider.animate({left: newLeftProperty}, 500);

    });

$("#leftButton").click(function(){
    leftProperty = parseInt(slider.css("left"));

    if (leftProperty < 0){
        newLeftProperty = leftProperty + 304;


    }

    else {
        newLeftProperty = 0;
    }

    slider.animate({left: newLeftProperty}, 500);
});
});
```

the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="carousel">
<h2>Recommended for You</h2>
<div id="leftButton" class="buttonPanel"></div>
<div id="display">
<ul id="carouselList">

</ul>
</div><!--display-->
<div id="rightButton" class="buttonPanel"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--carousel-->

<script>
$.getJSON('jsonData.json', function(data){
    var items=[];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        items.push(val);
        $("#carouselList").append(items[2]);
        var c =$("#carouselList li").size();
        $("#carouselList").css("width", c*250);
    });
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)? It will make it easier for others to help answer your question.

Comment: I figured it out. I calculated the width of the list based on the number list elements. Then I had to take that value and turn it into an integer and write an if statement asking if the negative left value was greater than or equal to the negative width minus 600ish then the left position is zero (resets the carousel)